# Is it bad to change collection view cell with property observer?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

```
class SceneCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            setSelected(bool: isSelected)
        }
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            setHighlighted(bool: isHighlighted)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.thumbnailImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    func update(with scene: Scene) {

    }

    private func setHighlighted(bool: Bool) {
        if bool {
            self.alpha = 0.5
        } else {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

    private func setSelected(bool: Bool) {
        if bool {
            self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
        } else {
            self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
    }
}
```

In my code, I change image view's layer border width to 2.5 when **isSelected** is set true.

When I select one cell and scroll collection view, I thought cell is remain selected state when reuse that selected cell, but reuse cell is change to unselected state. Second, when I went back to the selected cell and reused the unselected cell, I thought it was in an unselected state. But cell is automatically set selected.

Dose the collection view automatically manage these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question's code is working perfectly. Here is an alternative solution for recording cells' selections and apply settings for selected/deselected status.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //......

    var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let index = selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) {
            selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
        }
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //...
        cell.setSelected(selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)) //Remember to make the cell's setSelected() public.
        //...
    }

    //......
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly with reusing problem? I guess it's working perfectly when no scrolling, is it?

Comment: It hasn't reusing problem. My question is why this code works well.

Comment: Works well when scrolling!

Comment: It's okay. Is it bad to change cell's view with property observers?

Comment: I think collection view automatically manages selected index path and set isSelected property when reuse cells. So works well. Is it right? This is my doubtful point.

Comment: Yes, when collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false, it's working perfectly, like you said, collection view automatically manages selected index path. You can test it if it has problem when collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

Comment: Yes, my app doesn't need multiple selection. thanks!

Comment: I try to change allowsMutipleSelection to true. But there is no problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll let you know when I know the answer.

Comment: I just tried print observer property's old value and new value. When reuse cell, maybe collection view compare selectedIndexPath and current indexPath and set isSelected value properly.